# Is this interval in the domain?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking a calculus course and a question is given :

Is the interval

$
(-\infty  , -\sqrt2)
$

in the domain
$
\sqrt{2^x - x^3}
$

---

Here is my method of solution :

Taking $-\infty$ for x :

$
\sqrt{2 (-\infty)  - (-\infty) (-\infty) (-\infty) }
$

=
$
\sqrt{2 (-\infty)  - (-\infty) \infty }
$

=
$
\sqrt{2 (-\infty)  (\infty + \infty) }
$

=
$
\sqrt{-\infty + \infty }
$

=

$
\sqrt{0}
$

= 0

Taking $\sqrt{-2}$ for x :

$
\sqrt{2 (\sqrt{-2})  - (\sqrt{-2}) (\sqrt{-2}) (\sqrt{-2}) }
$

=
$
\sqrt{2 (\sqrt{-2})  - \sqrt{-2} - 2 }
$

=
$
\sqrt{2 (\sqrt{-2})  - (- 2) \sqrt{-2} }
$

=
$
\sqrt{2 (\sqrt{-2})  + 2 \sqrt{-2} }
$

The point $-\infty$ is not in the interval as 0 > $-\infty$

The point $-\sqrt2$ is not in the interval as this evaluates to an imaginary number when applied to the the domain.

In conclusion the interval 
$
(-\infty  , -\sqrt2)
$
in not the domain
$
\sqrt{2^x - x^3}
$

Comment: You CANNOT use infinity as a number!

Comment: You substituted $\sqrt{-2}$ instead of $-\sqrt{2}$. And $2^x$ became $2x$. And infinities can't be added that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $2^x$ is always positive $-x^3$ is positive for $x\leq 0$.

PS: your approach with limit points can only be used if you know that the function is monotone (and you function is not monotone). Moreover, as the other said in the comments, your way of "evaluating" the function at infinity and even at $-\sqrt{2}$ is wrong.

Another correct approach would have been finding the infimum of this function on the given domain, and show that it is greater or equal than $0$. In this case one also has to look at the boundary terms.

Comment: 'the infimum of this function' is 0 as the square root of a positive number is always positive ?

Comment: it is not zero. It is greater or equal than zero. The reason is the one I gave as a hint. Moreover you are not looking for where the function is positive, but only where it is well-defined. So your point is irrelevant at this stage.